# wurstmeister/Kafka : Issue with HOSTNAME_COMMAND and BROKER_ID_COMMAND In Docker swarm

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-swarm-mode

I have docker swarm with 3 node with following stack file

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    deploy:
       mode: global
    volumes:
      - /zookeeper/data:/data
      - /zookeeper/datalog:/datalog
    environment:
        ZOO_MY_ID: 1
        ZOO_PORT: 2181
        ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zookeeper:2888:3888

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    ports:
      - target: 9094
        published: 9094
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    deploy:
      mode: global
    environment:
      HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "docker info | grep 'Node Address:' | cut -d' ' -f 5"
      BROKER_ID_COMMAND: "{{`docker info -f ''{{.Swarm.NodeAddr}}'' | cut -d . -f 4`}}"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://_{HOSTNAME_COMMAND}:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./kafka:/var/lib/kafka/data
```

1. When i am trying to connect from filebeat producer with hostIP1:9094, hostIP2:9094, hostIP3:9094, getting error

   2021-06-22T13:22:01.215+0530    DEBUG   [kafka] kafka/client.go:385 Kafka publish failed with: dial tcp: lookup f0038421e470: no such host

It means following command returning container id to filebeat as a host IP, not actual host IP.

```
HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "docker info | grep 'Node Address:' | cut -d' ' -f 5"
```

2. Second issue with BROKER_ID_COMMAND, its giving following error at kafka , But if i run on linux machine it will give last digit of IP for broker ID

   org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value  for configuration broker.id: Not a number of type INT

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use Swarm rather than a Kafka Kubernetes operator and k3s, for example?

Comment: @OneCricketeer will that help? any referance?

Comment: Kubernetes is more complex than Swarm, but outside of that, application cluster setup is far easier https://strimzi.io/ + https://k3s.io